# Why "les croissants avec DU beurre" ?

Tags: articles, partitif, articles-definis

I have passed this https://french-online.ru/articletest/  test (72 %, congrats me) but the first answer was wrong and it is confusing me.

J’aime ... croissants avec ... beurre.

Okay, "croissant" is a countable noun, but even if it hadn’t be - after aimer there shouldn’t be a partitive article, so, anyway *J’aime les croissants* is right.

But why is "beurre" used with a partitive article? I thought I should use it if I talked about certain, definite nouns, i.e. with definition, like "*Le champ couvert de neige/ du neige blanche*";  if there is no definition I thought I shoudl just use "de" in case of the  noun being uncountable, and an article in the case of a countable noun.

Isn't it so?

Answer (score 4):

There is something not quite usual in this locution; the only solution from those proposed is "Jaime **les** croissants avec **du** beurre." and so the test is  quite right from the point of view of grammar and context. However, the context is quite rare. The usual locution is "croissant **au** beurre" (J'aime les croissants au beurre.). Croissants "**au** beurre" are croissants that are made using butter rather than some other type of fat. You can't say "avec du beurre" in this context.
 If you were to say "**avec du** beurre" you would be talking about quite something else, something that  a certain number of French people themselves might not undertand because it describes a practice that few people only know of or follow. It consists in splitting a croissant into two parts lengthwise and then spreading butter on the inside; you can spread it onto one only of the two pieces, then join the two parts together as a sandwich, and that definitely  makes for a buttery taste. You can also spread the butter onto each side and  eat them separately.

In this second (and rare) context the partitive makes sense then. Nevertheless, consider that in

- "Les croissants **au** (à le) beurre sont fabriqués avec **du** (de le) beurre."

you do use the partitive again  when talking about what they are made with ( a certain  amount out of the whole mass); it's the same idea as for the "croissant avec du beurre".

---

"De" here would mean "that are made out of butter", only butter or mostly butter: du pain de blé, de la farine de mais… Do you get it? You wouldn't have "avec" though: "des croissants de beurre". This, of course doesn't exit.

As you seemed to know about partitive in French, I assumed, however, that you knew about the contraction: "**de le** ==> **du**" for masculine nouns.

Comment: But even why du why not just de?

Comment: @АртурКлочко "De" here would mean "that are made out of butter", only butter or mostly butter: du pain **de** blé, de la farine **de** mais… Do you get it? You wouldn't have "avec" though: "des croissants de beurre". This, of course doesn't exit.

Comment: @АртурКлочко I assumed, however, that  you knew about the contraction: **de le** ==> **du** for masculine nouns.

Comment: You're right about the different meaning between "au beurre" vs "avec du beurre". I'm not too sure though about the low amount of people knowing that practice. Maybe that's a cultural difference between France and Belgium but in Belgium it doesn't seem so odd. At least not more odd than "les croissants avec de la confiture".

Comment: @LaurentS. That's interesting; I wouldn't say it's odd as this adjective implies possibly something strange. It just seems rare. In France, at least for the little part of it where I could see for myself, I can  remember of only one spell when I saw some people doing that, which , of course, prompted me to try.

Comment: Instead of using butter, French people would prefer to add coffee or jelly with it, so you would have *J'aime les croissants avec du café* or *J'aime les croissants avec de la confiture*. Also, we used *du*/*de la* instead of *de* because you can't count how many you used (without using a tool); if it would have been a biscuit, you could have used *un* / *des*

Answer (score 2):

La phrase couramment utilisée en français est :

> J'aime **les** croissants **au** beurre.

Ce qui signifie que les croissants sont réalisés avec une pâte (feuilletée) contenant du beurre.

> J’aime les croissants avec du beurre.

Signifie des croissants avec du beurre ajouté par dessus, ce qui est grammaticalement correct mais n'est pas employé dans le langage courant.

Comment: The question is why **du**, not **de**?